# SMS forwarding Twilio based on multiple Conditions to set groups

Tags: if-statement, conditional-statements, twilio, sms, message

I would like to forward a SMS message to a group of SMS numbers based on a conditional match.

I found SMS forwarding to another SMS number and SMS forwarding to a group of SMS numbers but I am unsure how to add the conditional match factor.

The SMS number sending the message will remain the same. I would like when this SMS message sends a message that based on a conditional match in the message (Location) it sends it to the group associated with that match.

Meaning the Message "Location A Alarm" forward this alarm to the group of phone numbers for Location A.

Comment: Can you please explain what you've tried so far and where you are stuck now?  This [guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) explains how to ask good questions.

Comment: I have tried the SMS to SMS forwarding and the SMS to Multiple SMS forwarding but I am unfamiliar with the Twilio platform. I am stuck with the part of taking the body of the message and deciding which group of numbers should receive the SMS.

Comment: That's still a bit vague. Maybe you can start at this [docs page](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/webhooks/sms-webhooks#type-1-incoming-message) and add an `if` statement which decides on the [`to`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/messaging/twiml/message#attributes-to) attribute of the TwiML response